# VS 2010 compiler error "c2678 no operator found that converts const std::string", but nothing is declared const

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

My source code is about as simple as it gets:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

void test() {
    set<string> *S = new set<string>;
    S->insert("hi"); 
    S->insert("lo");
    set<string> *T = new set<string>;
    T->insert("lo");
    set<string> *s = new set<string>;
    set<string>::iterator l=s->begin();
    set_difference(S->begin(),S->end(),T->begin(),T->end(),l);
}
```

So why do I get a compiler error:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(4671): error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
```

The set "s" is just a set of strings, nothing const there.

Comment: you need back_inserter for l

Comment: Do not "new" STL data structures. C++ is not Java. All you need is `set<string> S;` And you can begin using it.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use an [inserter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) for the set_difference:

```
   set_difference(S->begin(),S->end(),T->begin(),T->end(),std::inserter(*s, l))
```

Building on the comment from Neil Kirk the "exception safe" way of writing this code would be this:

```
set<string> S;
S.insert("hi"); 
S.insert("lo");
set<string> T;
T.insert("lo");
set<string> s;
set<string>::iterator l=s.begin();
set_difference(S.begin(),S.end(),T.begin(),T.end(),std::inserter(s, l));
```

In modern C++ there is almost never a case where you need to use `new`.  If you do need to dynamically allocate you should be using `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.